# Scala case matching using inductive structure failing while mapping a list

Tags: scala, recursion, filter, pattern-matching

Here I am attempting to to achieve the following:

1. Using recursion, return a new list that consist of all elements of the list l that return true when the function f is called on them.
2. The returned list elements must preserve the same order as in the original list.

Edit:

So far, I've be able to eliminate type my type mismatch errors. My goal of iterating through a list given the definitions and returning a new list still seems far off.

```
sealed trait NumList
case object Nil extends NumList
case class Cons(n: Int, l: NumList) extends NumList

def filterNumList(l: NumList, f: Int => Boolean): NumList = {
    l match {
            case Nil => Nil
            case Cons(i, Nil) => Cons(i, Nil)
            case Cons(i, Cons(j, Nil)) if f(i) == false => filterNumList(Cons(j, Nil),f)
            case Cons(i, Cons(j, Nil)) if f(i) == true => filterNumList(Cons(i, Nil),f)
            case Cons(i, rest) if f(i) == true => filterNumList(Cons(i,rest),f)
            case Cons(i, Cons(j, rest)) if f(i) == false => filterNumList(Cons(j, rest),f)
        }
}

val l1 = Cons(12, Cons(25, Cons(37, Nil)))
def f1(j: Int): Boolean =  j <= 25 && j >= 12
println(filterNumList(l1, f1))
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. You should fix compilation errors firstly.

Comment: `e` is not defined, `f == true` and `f == false` don't make sense.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I've corrected the e. If the function f returns true I want to take that element to the new list and continue testing the rest of the list. I'm not sure where the logic is incorrect.

Comment: `f == true` and `f == false` still don't make sense. `f` is a function, you are not supposed to compare it with boolean.

Comment: *"If the function f returns true..."* Returns on what input?

Comment: @DmytroMitin I see, I figured it was correct because the return value is a boolean derived from the test cases which generate a boolean. Oh! I should have added the parameter i, right?

Comment: Maybe in the 2nd case you want `f(i) == true`. But in the 3rd case you have two values  `f(i)` and `f(j)`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Got it. In the 3rd case I need to skip the element i and then start with j because I'm implying that i is not being added into the new list. I hope that was clear

Comment: @DmytroMitin I don't see where `f(j)` should be used. What I have now gives me an infinite loop, `f(i) == true` in both the 2nd and 3rd case

Comment: Ok, it's better. What if you have case `Cons(i, Nil) if f(i) == false`? Do you really need nested case (i and j)? Can be `Cons(i, rest) if f(i) == true` and `Cons(i, rest) if f(i) ==  false` enough? You should learn how to debug your code.

Comment: For your `l1` move step by step and see why your recursion doesn't stop.

Comment: Use debugger or add `println(l)` to the beginning of your recursiive method.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Going in for updates.

Comment: You added even more cases than you had. Can you see that there remain possible `l` not covered by any of your cases? Do you really need all those cases? Why do you think that `Nil`, `Cons(i, rest) if f(i) == true` and `Cons(i, rest) if f(i) ==  false` are not enough? Did you start to debug your code? Did you add `println(l)` to the beginning of the method? Can you see what is happening with `l`? You can also add `println(1)`, ..., `println(6)` to your cases in order to see what case are you in at every step. Can you see what case do you get into each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cases you have to explore are simpler than what you are laying down.

The ones you are interested in are:

1. the list is empty:

   - nothing to do here, just return the empty list
2. the first item of the list satisfies the predicate:

   - construct a list that

     - contains the first item
     - followed by applying the filter to the rest of the list
3. the first item *does not* satisfy the predicate:

   - just return the result of applying the filter to the rest of the list

In pseudo code this would be:

```
function filter(list, predicate)
  if empty(list)
    return the empty list
  else
    if predicate(head(list)) is true
      cons(head(list), filter(tail(list), predicate))
    else
      filter(tail(list), predicate)
```

In Scala this should cover your requirements:

```
sealed trait NumList
case object Nil extends NumList
case class Cons(n: Int, l: NumList) extends NumList

def filterNumList(l: NumList, f: Int => Boolean): NumList = {
  l match {
    case Nil                         => Nil
    case Cons(head, tail) if f(head) => Cons(head, filterNumList(tail, f))
    case Cons(head, tail)            => filterNumList(tail, f)
  }
}

val l1 = Cons(12, Cons(25, Cons(37, Nil)))
def f1(j: Int): Boolean = j <= 25 && j >= 12
println(filterNumList(l1, f1))
```

You can play with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/dByAKfH6Sk2FDcTlS4Ielg/2).

Comment: I'm not sure of why this was downvoted, it seems fairly helpful. If there is something that can be improved upon I'm happy to do that, but without any context it's quite difficult to do so.

Comment: I guess fully complete and exhaustive code for standard function `filter` (which can be found in every library and everywhere in internet) can't be helpful for a student who tries to learn how to write recursion and how to debug his/her code.

Comment: I guess we have different ways to see how to use StackOverflow. Cheers!

Comment: Obviously. Cheers!

Comment: @stefanobaghino @DmytroMitin I'm not sure how I deviated so far away from my notes. I think I was coding out of desperation to get something on paper. Thank you guys ```def map(l: List[Int], f: (Int) => Int): List[Int] = l match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case e :: rest => f(e) :: map(rest, f)
} ```

Comment: @stefanobaghino [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) 1) *"It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment."* 2) *"Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines"* Removing downvote.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @Garrett I guess later on you will learn about tail-recursive functions. Since sadly this implementation of `filter` can produce a **StackOverflow** error _(curiously the name of this site)_. Just a quick hint in case you want to dive deep into that topic, you would need an accumulator.